# More generic way to set an objects value within React handleChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formik

I have a component in React, I need to take a value from the radio button being checked and then set that value within an object in my Formik values. If a different radio button is selected within the group I need to set the previously selected one to false, is there a standard way of doing this? I'm using an object within my Formik values as the field holds a date as well as the attribute from the radio button, you can see where I place the date into the object using `handleTime`, so I can't just null the field and place the new item in.

I'm currently doing the following in my component to update the Formik `time_frame` value.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Col, Row} from 'react-bootstrap';
import Radio from "./radio";


export default class EventTimeFrame extends Component {
    state = {
        eventTimeFrame: [
            {id: 1, value: "one_off", label: "ONE OFF", checked: false},
            {id: 2, value: "recurring", label: "RECURRING", checked: false},
        ]
    }

    handleOccurance = value => {
        let timeCopy = {...this.props.values.time_frame}
        if (value.target.checked) {
            if (value.target.value === "one_off") {
                timeCopy[value.target.value] = true
                timeCopy["recurring"] = false
            } else {
                timeCopy[value.target.value] = true
                timeCopy["one_off"] = false
            }
        }
        this.props.onChange("time_frame", timeCopy)

        this.setState(prevState => ({
            eventTimeFrame: prevState.eventTimeFrame.map(
                el => el.value === value.target.value ? {...el, checked: true} : el
            )
        }))
    };

    handleTime = value => {
        let timeCopy = {...this.props.values.time_frame}
        timeCopy["start"] = new Date(value.target.value);
        this.props.onChange("time_frame", timeCopy)
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <h4 className="ui centered question-header text-center">ONE OFF OR RECURRING EVENT?</h4>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    {
                        this.state.eventTimeFrame.map((timeFrame) => {
                            return (
                                <Radio name="time_frame" key={timeFrame.value}
                                       onChange={this.handleOccurance} checked={timeFrame.checked} {...timeFrame} />
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <h4 className="question-header date-text">PLEASE ENTER THE FIRST DAY OF YOUR EVENT</h4>
                    </Col>
                    <Col>
                        <input type="date" className="form-control date" name="start"
                               onChange={this.handleTime}/>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I feel like there has to be a standard way of dealing with things like this

Comment: Could you please include the render method of EventTimeFrame, and provide an example of how the component is being implement. It will save us from making too many assumptions about your code :)

Comment: I have added the render method, thanks! @RoMilton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're correct by suspecting there's a simpler way  Some feedback:

- Don't store the `eventTimeFrame` in state, a constant will do.
- The standard way of using radio input values in Formik is to define one value in `initialValues` for the entire group. Formik will set its value to the *selected* option.
- Storing all options in `values` would have been fine if you were using checkboxes instead of radio buttons.
- You wrote your own custom `onChange` handlers, but it would be simpler to just use Formik's provided `onChange` handlers. I only use my own handler if I have to, for example when formatting a value before setting it with `setFieldValue()`

See below:

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-example-forked-11tjk?file=/index.js)

```
// outside of component
const timeFrameTypes = [
  { id: "one_off", label: "ONE OFF" },
  { id: "recurring", label: "RECURRING" }
];

// in component's render function:
<Formik
  initialValues={{
    time_frame: {
      type: "",
      start: ""
    }
  }}
  onSubmit={async (values) => {
    // do something with values
  }}
>
  {({ handleSubmit }) => {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <h4 className="ui centered question-header text-center">
                ONE OFF OR RECURRING EVENT?
              </h4>
            </Col>
          </Row>
          <Row>
            {timeFrameTypes.map((timeFrameType) => {
              return (
                <Field
                  key={timeFrameType.id}
                  component={Radio}
                  name="time_frame.type"
                  id={timeFrameType.id}
                  label={timeFrameType.label}
                />
              );
            })}
          </Row>
          <Row>
            <Col>
              <h4 className="question-header date-text">
                PLEASE ENTER THE FIRST DAY OF YOUR EVENT
              </h4>
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <Field name="time_frame.start">
                {({ field }) => <input type="date" {...field} />}
              </Field>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </div>
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }}
</Formik>
```